# Подсчет ссылок в QSharedMemory

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите пожалуйста, где именно в исходниках QT я могу найти реализацию подсчета ссылок для разделяемой памяти QSharedMemory? Хотелось бы получить файл и строку.

У самого не получается найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно смотреть системно зависимую реализацию интерфейса класса `QSharedMemoryPrivate` из `/qt/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qsharedmemory_p.h`, конкретно функции `attach`.
Под `Linux` используется функция [shmat](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=shmat&category=2&russian=0), в которой инкрементируется счетчик `shm_nattch`  "подстыковываний сегмента разделяемой памяти shmid к адресному пространству вызывающего процесса". Смотрите `qsharedmemory_systemv.cpp`.
Под Windows нужно смотреть `qsharedmemory_win.cpp`. Там используется библиотека `memoryapi.h`
[MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile).